# Keyboard not working at initial FDE Passphrase screen (20.04.1)

Tags: grub2, 20.04, encryption, initramfs

Symptom:

- system reboots to the Passphrase screen, but keypresses are not registered (no response to typing correct, or bogus, passphrase + )
- it's a fresh install of 20.04 (20.04.1 media) on a HP envy x360
- basic specs: amd ryzen7 4700U w/ radeon, 2-in-2

Other observations while in this state:

- `capslock` successfully toggles it's indicator light on both internal & usb keyboards.  On usb keyboard, numlock does as well - but the internal kbd has a dedicated light (tested in liveusb).
- physical power button immediately shuts off the device from the Passphrase prompt
- I don't see any response to `ctrl-alt-del` (suggested below) or any other key combo I can conjur.

Doing a lot of DuckDuckGo'ing, I see that over the years there have been a number of reproductions with ~identical symptoms.  I've tried the workarounds attempted (no avail) and further those issues are very old or specify some criteria that my system doesn't match.  Details of these at end here

I've tried, based on workarounds offered in the similar issues:

- using a usb keyboard
- blacklisting `intel_vbtn` + `update-initramfs`
- `chroot`ing to the new install from usb media and `apt update && apt upgrade -y`
- setting `nosplash` in `grub` + `update-grub`
- re-installing with & without secure boot enabled in the bios
- re-installing with & without non-free (binary blobs) selected

A few nearly identical issues, but suggested workarounds don't seem to help me.

- same issue, 5 years ago: [Full Disk Encryption Passphrase at Boot: Keyboard not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/613241/full-disk-encryption-passphrase-at-boot-keyboard-not-working).
- seemed plausibly related, but my 2-in-1 system seems to correctly report `/sys/class/dmi/id/chassis_type`==31 (from liveusb at least) https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1894017

As this is an FDE system (and no input methods seem to work) I'm not aware of any more step to take - please help!

Comment: on the external usb keyboard - I see that `CAPS` and `NUMLOCK` keys _do_ toggle the respective indicator lights

Comment: Does ctrl-alt-del at the passphrase prompt do anything? On mine (20.04), it reboots. This might help narrow down the problem.

Comment: @bitinerant - ctrl-alt-del (I also tried just about every other combo i could think of) doesn't have any discernible affect.  The only feedback from the system I get is the caps-key (on both internal and usb keyboard) and the numlock key on external (internal key doesn't appear to have a dedicated numlock light, though I can't tell for sure)

Comment: not getting any advice yet here or elsewhere, i decided to try to update my kernel.  I went with the 20.04 HWE "edge" (`apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-20.04-edge`) as this seemed marginally more likely to have been tested together.  I installed this and updated grub & initramfs, rebooted.  It booted to desktop *_ONCE_*; after boot I let ubuntu software do an upgrade; after the next reboot I'm back to where I started.  The kernel that booted once was 5.8.0.33 - and I would believe that remained unchanged for the subsequent failing boots.